# How to achive result with regex replacement

Tags: .net, regex, regex-negation, regex-group

Hello there I need regex expression which can do following transformation

```
alabala-1000 Intern -> alabala/alabala-1000/Intern
```

part before minus sign should be extracted and then space between alabala-1000 and Intern should be detected aswell

Comment: @PedroLobito `if not code: pass`

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @KindStranger That's a good one ;)

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: @user3499805 `C#` or `VB` ?

Comment: @PedroLobito  C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(.+)-(\d+)\s+(.+)", @"$1/$1-$2/$3");
```

---

[image]

---

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TASRp7/2)
[C# Demo](https://ideone.com/xhcKI3)